# Code for the Hackerearth practice problem for singly linked list being core dumped

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, stack, singly-linked-list

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include<vector>
    #include <stack>
    using namespace std;

    class Node
    {
    public:
    int data;
    Node* next;
    };

    int main()
    {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    Node* head = new Node;
    Node* ptr = new Node;
    head = NULL;
    // take the input for the linked list;

    for (int i = 0; i< n ;i++)
    {
        int num;
        cin >> num;
        Node* temp = new Node;
        temp->data = num;
        temp->next = NULL;
        if(head == NULL)
        {
            head = temp;
            //head->next = NULL;
            ptr = head;
        }
        else
        {
           ptr->next = temp;
           ptr = temp;
        }

        // linked list made
     }
    Node* head1 = new Node;
    head1 = head;

    //ptr->data = NULL;
    //ptr->next = NULL;

    stack <int> stk;
    ptr = head1;

    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        if(head1->data % 2 != 0)
        {
            head1 = head1->next;
        }

        else
        {
            ptr = head1;
            while(ptr->data % 2==0 && ptr != NULL)
            {
                stk.push(ptr->data);
                ptr = ptr->next;
            }

            while(head1 != ptr)
            {
            int n ;
            n = stk.top();
            head1->data = n;
            head1 = head1->next;
            stk.pop();
            }

        }
       //head1 = ptr;
        // replace the values again in the linked list
    }

    // print the linked list

    while(head != NULL)
    {
        cout << head->data << " ";
        head = head->next;
    }


  }
```

This is a practice problem - 1 for singly linked list on HackerEarth. The code is being compiled properly but runs into run time error and I'm not able to figure out why.

For example if the list is 
{24 , 18, 2 , 5 , 7 , 16 , 12 }
The returned list should be 
{2, 18 , 24 , 5 , 7 , 12 , 16}

The part of the linked list that is even numbered should be reversed leaving the rest of the linked list the same.

Also I'm very new to programming and am learning data structures and algorithms for the first time so please excuse any bad indentation and silly errors this time .I promise to get better.

Comment: See [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Checked and still stuck .

Comment: `Node *head = new Node;` then `head = NULL;` ??? (where does `head` point now??) In other words, you allocate storage for a `Node` saving the address to `head`, you then immediately overwrite that pointer with `NULL` losing your reference to your allocated block of memory creating a memory leak and leaving `head` pointing nowhere.

Comment: Thanks David!!
I thought we needed to initialize the pointer to something and that's why I made it NULL for the time being.
Realized my folly now!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a large number of logic problems in your code. To begin with, `head` and `ptr` do not need to be allocated. They simply serve as pointers to the beginning and end of your list (`tail` would be a more descriptive name for `ptr`), e.g.

```
    Node *head = nullptr, *tail = nullptr;  /* don't allocate */
```

Always validate your input, at least minimally, e.g.

```
    if (!(cin >> n))                        /* validate every input */
        return 1;
```

The only time you allocate is for `temp` within the read loop of values, e.g.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {           /* loop n times */
        int num;

        if (!(cin >> num))                  /* read/validate int input */
            return 1;

        Node *temp = new Node;              /* allocate new node */
        temp->data = num;                   /* initialize data & next */
        temp->next = nullptr;

        if (head == nullptr)                /* if 1st in list */
            head = tail = temp;             /* set head/tail to temp */
        else {
            tail->next = temp;              /* otherwise add at tail */
            tail = temp;
        }
    }
```

You can either reuse your `tail` pointer or simply declare a second pointer to preserve a pointer to the first in a series of nodes with even `node->data` members. The logic for reversing the sequence of even `node->data` members can all happen within a single traversal of the list.

Simply begin traversing your list. When an even node is encountered, save a pointer to the node and begin pushing data onto your stack. When an odd member (or end of list) is encountered so long as your stack has values, you simply iterate beginning with the node pointed to by your second pointer and use the `.top()` value from the stack as its new value, `.pop()`ing from your stack as you go. When your stack is empty -- repeat the entire process until the end of list (don't forget to handle the last set of nodes before the end)

```
    stack<int> stk {};                      /* declare stk & 2nd pointer */
    Node *iter2 = nullptr;
    for (Node *iter = head; iter; iter = iter->next)    /* iterate nodes */
        if (iter->data % 2 == 0) {          /* if even data */
            stk.push (iter->data);          /* add to stk */
            if (!iter2)                     /* if 2nd iter nullptr */
                iter2 = iter;               /* set to current node */
        }
        else if (iter2 && !stk.empty()) {   /* if odd data */
            /* loop while stk not empty and 2nd iter not nullptr */
            for (; !stk.empty() && iter2; stk.pop()) {
                iter2->data = stk.top();    /* pop from stk to node */
                iter2 = iter2->next;        /* advance 2nd iter */
            }
            iter2 = nullptr;                /* set to nullptr at end */
        }
```

to handle the final nodes in the list:

```
    /* update final nodes in list */
    for (; !stk.empty() && iter2; stk.pop()) {
        iter2->data = stk.top();
        iter2 = iter2->next;
    }
```

All that remains is outputting the modified list and freeing the allocated memory (for hackerrank -- you can skip freeing the memory). Adjust the output format as desired:

```
    cout << "modified: ";                   /* output modified list */
    for (Node *iter = head; iter;) {        /* iterate over list */
        cout << " " << iter->data;          /* output values */
        Node *victim = iter;                /* save poiter to node */
        iter = iter->next;                  /* advance to next */
        delete victim;                      /* delete victim */
    }
    cout << '\n';
```

Putting it altogether, you could do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

class Node {
  public:
    int data;
    Node *next;
};

int main ()
{
    int n;
    Node *head = nullptr, *tail = nullptr;  /* don't allocate */

    if (!(cin >> n))                        /* validate every input */
        return 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {           /* loop n times */
        int num;

        if (!(cin >> num))                  /* read/validate int input */
            return 1;

        Node *temp = new Node;              /* allocate new node */
        temp->data = num;                   /* initialize data & next */
        temp->next = nullptr;

        if (head == nullptr)                /* if 1st in list */
            head = tail = temp;             /* set head/tail to temp */
        else {
            tail->next = temp;              /* otherwise add at tail */
            tail = temp;
        }
    }

    cout << "original: ";                   /* output original list */
    for (Node *iter = head; iter; iter = iter->next)
        cout << " " << iter->data;
    cout << '\n';

    stack<int> stk {};                      /* declare stk & 2nd pointer */
    Node *iter2 = nullptr;
    for (Node *iter = head; iter; iter = iter->next)    /* iterate nodes */
        if (iter->data % 2 == 0) {          /* if even data */
            stk.push (iter->data);          /* add to stk */
            if (!iter2)                     /* if 2nd iter nullptr */
                iter2 = iter;               /* set to current node */
        }
        else if (iter2 && !stk.empty()) {   /* if odd data */
            /* loop while stk not empty and 2nd iter not nullptr */
            for (; !stk.empty() && iter2; stk.pop()) {
                iter2->data = stk.top();    /* pop from stk to node */
                iter2 = iter2->next;        /* advance 2nd iter */
            }
            iter2 = nullptr;                /* set to nullptr at end */
        }
    /* update final nodes in list */
    for (; !stk.empty() && iter2; stk.pop()) {
        iter2->data = stk.top();
        iter2 = iter2->next;
    }

    cout << "modified: ";                   /* output modified list */
    for (Node *iter = head; iter;) {        /* iterate over list */
        cout << " " << iter->data;          /* output values */
        Node *victim = iter;                /* save poiter to node */
        iter = iter->next;                  /* advance to next */
        delete victim;                      /* delete victim */
    }
    cout << '\n';
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Using your data from your question as input, and outputting both the original and modified lists, you would have:

```
$ ./bin/hrll
7 24 18 2 5 7 16 12
original:  24 18 2 5 7 16 12
modified:  2 18 24 5 7 12 16
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: 'Sir" Rankin . I cannot tell you how grateful I am to you for this effort you took to explain my shortcomings to me. I will be careful to take care of the above errors next time!

Comment: Glad it helped. It was a neat combination of a list and stack that took a bit of reading-between-the-lines to figure out what it was trying to do. After understanding it was simply reversing each sequence of even-numbers in the list, then it made sense. Good luck with your coding!

Answer (score 1):

Change line number 62 like - `while(ptr != NULL && ptr->data % 2==0)`

You should check the `ptr != null` condition first, if it is false, then the `ptr->data` will not be executed due to short-circuit evaluation.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Although, this will remove the core dump error, you will not get the desired output. Your code has logical mistakes too.

Comment: Never knew about this earlier